# How to Enable JDK 7 for Websphere Profile

Tags: java, websphere-8, ibm-jdk

I am using Websphere 5.5.0 with Default JDk version as 6.
I installed new jdk 7. The Jdk7 got enabled only for the `server` and not for the `entire profile`.

Then I ran the `managesdk` command to enable the Jdk 7 for the entire profile.

> managesdk.bat -enableProfile -profileName AppSrv01 -sdkName 1.7_64 -enableServers

But I see the below error:

> CWSDK0009E: Unexpected exception com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.ConfigServiceException: RepositoryException while updating documents in master repository 
>   CWSDK1018I: Profile AppSrv01 could not be enabled to use SDK 1.7_64. 
>   CWSDK1002I: The requested managesdk task failed. See previous messages

List available profiles has the following info:

`managesdk.bat -listenabledProfileAll`

> CWSDK1004I: Profile AppSrv01 :
>   CWSDK1006I: PROFILE_COMMAND_SDK = 1.6_64 
>   CWSDK1008I: Node mvm-wNode01 SDK name: 1.6_64 
>   CWSDK1009I: Server server1 SDK name: 1.7_64 
>   CWSDK1001I: Successfully performed the requested managesdk task.

Any help from anybody ?
Why cannot the profile be enabled for jdk7 ?

Comment: Is your profile stand alone or federated to deployment manager?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to WAS. How can I figure out if the profile is standalone or not ?

Comment: Run `serverstatus -all` command to see, if you have `nodeagent` or any other servers defined in the profile.

Comment: Well it looks like it is a standalone profile. There is no directory like `nodeagent`

Answer (score 0):

Finally able to resolve it through multiple `hits and trial`.

Looks like `managesdk` command needs different permissions from the user who accesses the admin console. 
`C:\nitesh\websphere8.5.5\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\bin`
`C:\nitesh\websphere8.5.5\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\bin\sdk`
`C:\nitesh\websphere8.5.5\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\properties\sdk`
`C:\nitesh\websphere8.5.5\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\properties`

Allowed `all` file permissions ( on the above folders ) to all the users.

Comment: managesdk is changing files on the file system, so you should use the user account that installed WebSphere. So run the command from that user. Changing files manually is really not recommended.

Comment: Oh yes. Sorry. I forgot to mention that after changing the file permissions, I ran the command:  .\managesdk.bat -enableProfile -profileName AppSrv01 -sdkName 1.7_64 which finally did the wonders. So the whole issue was `file permissions`. Strange enough though, I logged into via the same `user name` as the `user` which installed WAS. Changing files manually did not have the complete outcome, so was a worthless effort and definitely not recommended. Modified my answer.